# Configuring Web Deploy IIS User premissions

Tags: iis, webdeploy

I successfully configured IIS for Web Deploy and added a IIS Manager User.
The problem is when i try to publish, i get back error

> Error 1   Web deployment task failed. (Unable to perform the operation
>   ("Delete Directory")  for the specified directory ("2_0_50727"). This
>   can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this
>   operation for the user credentials you are using.   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.)  C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets   4270    5   WebAPI

Which shortly means, there are no premissions for user to handle root folder content. I couldn't figure out, **who is the user**, to give the permissions to.

The linked Microsoft page is telling, in most of the case, it's "Local Service", well it already has full control permissions. So i tried more "IUSR", "DefaultAppPool" - still not right ones. The temporary solution is to give permissions to "Everyone" and then it works... **but who's the right user**??

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://blogs.iis.net/krolson/using-iis-manager-accounts-for-web-deployment-tool-msdeploy-delegation There's a section with the title **"How to find out what account to add for IIS user ACLs"**

Comment: Did you build out IIS with the proper structure yet? Never use the defaultapppool, as that is a poor practice. You need a new site in IIS, a folder for the site to be published too, and a new IIS pool for the site to be hosted in.

Answer (score 5):

Right click the web site in IIS Manager and choose *Deploy -> Configure Web Deploy Publishing*. Choose your IIS-user and *Setup*, in order to give correct rights for publishing to that site.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add a rule (contentPath, createApp, dirPath, filePath, iisApp, runCommand) for your IIS Manager user in Manager Service Delegation?

And also I granted access to the site folder for LOCAL SERVICE because Web Management Service runs under this account and for NETWORK SERVICE because of Web Deployment Agent Service.